# hotchocolate (ChiliCream) different QueryTypes per request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, hotchocolate

From what I have seen the QueryType is built in the startup and stays static. from the documentation:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddGraphQLServer()
            .AddQueryType<QueryType>(); // here 
    }
}
```

This is called and I can debug it and so on.

The question is simple: can I have a different QueryType per request (eventually filtered by an API key).

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that is possible with version 12. I am working on the docs for that.

Comment: Nice! The prerelease for the v12 is already in nuget. Can you put the code here if not much trouble? much appreciated!

Comment: @MichaelIngmarStaib hey! I noticed that the 12v is now out. Can I get the documentation about this subject? I can't seem to find it.